# Wrap caption in multipage lstlisting environment

Tags: floats, captions, multicol

I am following the [accepted answer from this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117836/code-listing-spanning-multiple-pages-with-captions-at-top) to extend an lstlisting across multiple pages.  It works great, however if my caption is too long the continued caption doesn't wrap, and this is an issue as I have to use a 2-column format.

For example, if I have:

```
Listing 1: Excerpted implementation of sorting application.
```

The first caption appears correct as:

```
Listing 1: Excerpted implementation of
sorting application.
```

However, when it spans multiple pages, the caption on the continued page doesn't wrap and writes into the second column.

For reference, here is the initial definition:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\lstset{
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=false,
frame=single,
}

\newcommand\mylstcaption{}

\surroundwithmdframed[
hidealllines=true,
middleextra={
  \node[anchor=west] at (O|-P)
    {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):~\mylstcaption};},
secondextra={
  \node[anchor=west] at (O|-P)
    {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):~\mylstcaption};},
splittopskip=2\baselineskip
]{lstlisting}
```

And a sample implementation:

```
\renewcommand\mylstcaption{Excerpted C implementation of legacy sorting application.}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, caption=\mylstcaption, label=l:sort1]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a sensible value (`\columnwidth`, for example) for the `text width` key of the `\node`s:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\lstset{
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=false,
xleftmargin=1em,
frame=single,
numbers=left,
numbersep=5pt,
}

\newcommand\mylstcaption{}

\surroundwithmdframed[
hidealllines=true,
middleextra={
  \node[anchor=south west,text width=\columnwidth] at (O|-P)
    {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):~\mylstcaption};},
secondextra={
  \node[anchor=south west,text width=\columnwidth] at (O|-P)
    {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):~\mylstcaption};},
splittopskip=2\baselineskip
]{lstlisting}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\mylstcaption{Example listing of code with a long caption spanning several lines in a two-column document. this is just a test for the example.}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, caption=\mylstcaption, label=lst:c1]

struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for completeness, here's the same idea but using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and its interaction with `listings`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\lstset{
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  xleftmargin=1em,
  frame=single,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
}

\newtcblisting{TCBlisting}[1][]{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  listing only,
  listing remove caption=false,
  listing options={#1},
  overlay middle and last={
  \node[anchor=south west,text width=\columnwidth] at (frame.north west)
    {\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting\  (Cont.):~\mylstcaption};
  }
}

\newcommand\mylstcaption{}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\mylstcaption{Example listing of code with a long caption spanning several lines in a two-column document. this is just a test for the example.}
\begin{TCBlisting}[language=C,caption={\mylstcaption}]
struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif

\end{TCBlisting}
\end{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, caption=\mylstcaption, label=lst:c1]

struct safe_buffer {
struct list_head node;

/* original request */
void    *ptr;
size_t  size;
int direction;

/* safe buffer info */
struct dmabounce_pool *pool;
void    *safe;
dma_addr_t  safe_dma_addr;
};

struct dmabounce_pool {
unsigned long   size;
struct dma_pool *pool;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long   allocs;
#endif
};

struct dmabounce_device_info {
struct device *dev;
struct list_head safe_buffers;
#ifdef STATS
unsigned long total_allocs;
unsigned long map_op_count;
unsigned long bounce_count;
int attr_res;
#endif
struct dmabounce_pool   small;
struct dmabounce_pool   large;

rwlock_t lock;

int (*needs_bounce)(struct device *, dma_addr_t, size_t);
};

#ifdef STATS
static ssize_t dmabounce_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
char *buf)
{
struct dmabounce_device_info *device_info = dev->archdata.dmabounce;
return sprintf(buf, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu\n",
device_info->small.allocs,
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs - device_info->small.allocs -
device_info->large.allocs,
device_info->total_allocs,
device_info->map_op_count,
device_info->bounce_count);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(dmabounce_stats, 0400, dmabounce_show, NULL);
#endif

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Heh, I debated posting a comment asking for clarification in your answer to the other question, but figured this would get more visibility.  Thanks!